# Simple SQL if/else clause fails

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to do a simple if/else clause in sql (Running with mysql/phpmyadmin). But I get 
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
SET @age = 50;

IF @age >  60
THEN 
Select `table1`.`Name` FROM table1 WHERE `Age` = 'Old'
ELSE
Select `table1`.`Name` FROM tablel WHERE `Age` = 'NotSoOld'
END IF;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Don't know. You could rewrite as `Select table1.Name FROM tablel WHERE Age = CASE WHEN @age >  60 THEN Old ELSE NotSoOld END` though

Comment: MySQL does have some very informative error messages. It's great, especially when you have 700 lines of SQL code, with `an error in its syntax`

Answer (score 2):

tablel (L minus) instead of table1 (the number one) ?

Comment: +1 Good spot even though that wouldn't give a syntax error I think.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with using the case statement instead. Thank for the clue Martin!
[SQL: IF clause within WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause)