# Can use IF() in a SELECT Query but not UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement

I've always used IF() in a a SELECT query as :

```
  SELECT
    IF(p.A=value,p.B,p.C) AS photo
FROM prof p
WHERE...
```

But when I use UPDATE and IF() like this SQL seems not to work, is it normal to can't use If() in an UPDATE Query ?

```
UPDATE table
SET IF(p.A=value,p.B,p.C) = value2
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can re-work the logic to this

```
p.B = if(p.A=$value, $value2, p.B), // set B=$value2 is p.A=$value
p.C = if(p.A=$value, p.C, $value2)  // set C=$value2 where p.A<>$value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the results of the IF expression since it isn't directly stored in a table. The update statement expects the left-hand-side of the set expressions to be column names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CASE....WHEN...THEN like this

```
UPDATE table
```

SET
p.A =
(
CASE
WHEN
   (p.A==value)
THEN
   value2
ELSE
   value3
END
)
WHERE
......

[OR you need to go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause)

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE 
    table
SET
    value2 = (SELECT IF(p.A=value,p.B,p.C) AS photo FROM prof p WHERE table.id=...)
```

Only MySQL 4.1+