# Doubling up on WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to do something like what's happening here in the where statement `@Age` param?

```
 @AGE Varchar(8)

 SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE 
 (
 If @AGE='man'
  then (AGE = 'man' or AGE = 'boy')
  else (AGE = 'man')
 )
 AND City IS NULL
```

Comment: `AGE='man' OR (@AGE='MAN' and AGE='boy')`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I don't think it's as simple as that e.g. consider that when `@AGE = 'man'` and `AGE = 'boy'` the OP's search condition is TRUE whereas yours is FALSE. –

Comment: @onedaywhen: Why, it would be True. First comparison yields False, second and third yield True. The conjunction of the last two yields True as well, and the disjunction of False and True is, again, True.

Comment: @AndriyM: Not sure what you mean by first, second and third. For the values in the case I gave, `If @AGE='man' then (AGE = 'man' or AGE = 'boy')` would evaluate TRUE and the `ELSE` condition would not be tested.

Comment: @AndriyM: ...I've added some test code to my answer.

Comment: @onedaywhen - I believe Andriy was referring to the 3 conditions in my first comment, in the order in which they appear. For `@AGE='man'` and `AGE='boy'`, my expression is `TRUE`, the same as the OPs.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Yes, I was talking about the three comparisons in Damien's suggestion, sorry for not clarifying that before. Also, thanks for the test script!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I see it now: You changed 'man' to 'MAN' and I'm using a case sensitive collation -- doesn't everyone? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, something like this:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE 
((@AGE='man'
   AND (AGE = 'man' or AGE = 'boy'))
OR
(@AGE <> 'man'
  AND (AGE = 'man')))
AND City IS NULL
```

Note the condition `@AGE <> 'man'`may need to be tweaked depending on whether the @AGE variable can be null.

I answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause/87992#87992).

> This is a very common technique in a WHERE clause. If you want to
>   apply some "IF" logic in the WHERE clause all you need to do is add
>   the extra condition with an boolean AND to the section where it needs
>   to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

one way of doing this is with `EXEC` and build the String command by `If's`.

something like this :

```
declare @t nvarchar(max)
@AGE Varchar(8)
set @t=' SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE '


 If @AGE='man' set @t=@t+'(AGE = ''man'' or AGE = ''boy'')'
  else  set @t=@t+'(AGE = 'man')'

set @t=@t+' AND City IS NULL'
```

Answer (score 1):

In conjunctive normal form ("a series of ANDs", less dependent on parans):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE ( @AGE <> 'man' OR (AGE IN ('man', 'boy') ) )
       AND ( @AGE = 'man' OR AGE = 'man' )
       AND CITY IS NULL;
```

The idea here is to use the implication rewrite rule:

```
( IF x THEN y )  is equivalent to  ( NOT ( x ) OR y )
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
WITH T 
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'man', NULL), 
                     (2, 'boy', NULL), 
                     (3, 'girl', NULL)
             ) AS T (NAME, AGE, CITY)
     ),
     Params
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('man'), 
                     ('boy'), 
                     ('girl')
             ) AS T (p_AGE)
     ), 
     Results
     AS
     (
      SELECT Params.*, T.*, 
             CASE WHEN     ( ( p_AGE <> 'man' OR (AGE IN ('man', 'boy') ) ) AND ( p_AGE = 'man' OR AGE = 'man' ) )  THEN 'TRUE'
                  WHEN NOT ( ( p_AGE <> 'man' OR (AGE IN ('man', 'boy') ) ) AND ( p_AGE = 'man' OR AGE = 'man' ) )  THEN 'FALSE'
                  ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
             END AS result_onedaywhen, 
             CASE WHEN     ( AGE='man' OR (p_AGE='MAN' and AGE='boy') )  THEN 'TRUE'
                  WHEN NOT ( AGE='man' OR (p_AGE='MAN' and AGE='boy') )  THEN 'FALSE'
                  ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
             END AS result_Damien_The_Unbeliever
        FROM T, Params
     )
SELECT * 
  FROM Results;
```

Answer (score 0):

OR you could use [decode functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

Comment: Question is tagged `sql-server`. `DECODE` doesn't exist on SQL Server.