# How to use IF ELSE inside WHERE clause

Tags: sql

Is it possible to use IF ELSE inside WHERE clause something like this...

```
WHERE transactionId like @transactionId
AND transactionType like @transactionType
AND customerId like @customerId
IF(@transactionType='1')
AND qTable.statusId like 'SIGNED'
ELSE
AND rTable.statusId like 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: IF clause within WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `IF ELSE` statement within the `WHERE` clause. Use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) instead:

```
WHERE transactionId like @transactionId
AND transactionType like @transactionType
AND customerId like @customerId
AND CASE WHEN @transactionType = '1' THEN qTable.statusId like 'SIGNED' 
    ELSE rTable.statusId like 'ACTIVE' END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE transactionId like @transactionId
AND transactionType like @transactionType
AND customerId like @customerId
AND 
  ((@transactionType='1' AND qTable.statusId like 'SIGNED')
OR 
  (@transactionType <> '1' AND like 'ACTIVE') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
WHERE transactionId like @transactionId
AND transactionType like @transactionType
AND customerId like @customerId
AND ((transactionType='1' and qTable.statusId like 'SIGNED') or (transactionType <> '1' and rTable.statusId like 'ACTIVE'))
```