# if-else / Case in sql server where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement, case, where-clause

In table Requets, have RequestNo, DTTDay, DMRDay, CombineDay, etc

I want to select the details when :

```
if CombineDay <> 0
        will select the data when CombineDay < 24
else 
        will select the data when (DTTDay < 24 or DMRDay < 24)
```

Have tried

```
select * from Request
where Case when CombineDay <> 0 then 
        CombineDay < 24
      else 
        DTTDay < 24 or DMRDay < 24
```

But its like something wrong with the query. Appreciate any help. Thanks

ps : have no idea what to put on Title

Edit: Sample Table

```
RequestNo   BookingNo   DTTDay  DMRDay  CombineDay

SR-xx       Pxx         0       0       14
SR-xx       Pxx         8       0       0
SR-xx       Pxx         0       0       28
```

Edit:
i think my explanation is not very clear. Ok, the sample data above the the original data. From that table, i want to select details where firstly it check if CombineDay <> 0, it will select the detail when `CombineDay < 24`. And else, it will select the details when `(DTTDay < 24 or DMRDay < 24)`

Comment: Please provide a sample table and output OR create a fiddle.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it computes a scalar *value*. It's not a control flow statement.  And I'm afraid your explanation isn't very clear - I can see you've added some sample data - so what is the expected *result* when querying against that data? Or if it is, in fact, the expected result, what was the original data in the table?

Comment: @Ullas - have put the sample table.

Comment: And what is `CombineFreeDay` - is that a typo, or is it meant to be some kind of parameter to the query?

Comment: Have you tried this way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from Request where (CombineFreeDay <> 0 and CombineDay < 24)
  or (CombineFreeDay = 0 and (DTTDay < 24 or DMRDay < 24))
```

Comment: can you help me to edit your answer by change the table name to Request since i unintentionally put the original table name before? hope you dont mind. Tqvm