# SQL Server If condition at where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to make a select query, I have several parameters but depending on the value I add the parameter to the where clause. I do not want to use dynamic query.
For example this is my stored declaration:

```
EXEC GETProducts @ProductID INT = -1, @ProductName NVARCHAR(100) = NULL, @ProductManufacturerID INT = -1
```

I want all the products manufactured by ManufacturerID = 3

```
EXEC GETProducts -1, NULL, 3
```

I would like a query like this, I know it does no work, I also tried with CASE, but not working.

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE 
IF(@ProductID > -1)
BEGIN
 ProductID = @ProductID
END
AND
IF(@ProductName <> '')
BEGIN
 ProductName = @ProductName 
END
AND
IF(@ProductManufacturerID > -1)
BEGIN
 ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID 
END
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Show what you tried with `CASE` since that will be much closer to a working solution than `IF`.

Comment: Also if you can try to show what you start with and what your output and expected output is.

Comment: A case statement seems reasonable in this situation over the `IF` statement just because of how messy your code might get

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog covers a lot of options

Comment: @MarkHill `IF` is completely invalid since it's for program flow, not expression evaluation, and can't be used inside a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @DStanley oh, yes you're right, duh. Brain fart! I need my coffee this morning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: IF clause within WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause)

Comment: Is not the same question...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a combination of `AND`s and `OR`s instead of `CASE` or `IF`:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE 
(@ProductID <= -1 OR ProductID = @ProductID)
AND
(@ProductName = '' OR ProductName = @ProductName)
AND
(@ProductManufacturerID <= -1 OR ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID)
```

However I would note that `NULL` is *generally* preferred to "magic" numbers and strings for special cases:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE 
(@ProductID IS NULL OR ProductID = @ProductID)
AND
(@ProductName IS NULL OR ProductName = @ProductName)
AND
(@ProductManufacturerID IS NULL OR ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID)
```

Comment: Using OR, wouldn't he select cases in which only one of the two considitions meet?
Supose that @PruductID is -3 and ProductID is 5. Since the clause
     (@ProductID <= -1 OR ProductID = @ProductID)
evaluates true, it will actually select it.

Comment: @BlackAdder Correct.  The intent is likely to use any negative number as a "magic number" that would select ALL products (effectively to NOT filter by product ID).  I'm guessing in this case but it's a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product
WHERE 
    (@ProductID = -1 OR ProductID = @ProductID)
AND (@ProductName = '' OR ProductName = @ProductName)
AND (@ProductManufacturerID = -1 OR ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a bit here. You probably want to write:

```
WHERE 
(@ProductID > -1 AND ProductID = @ProductID)
OR
(@ProductName <> '' AND ProductName = @ProductName )
OR
(@ProductManufacturerID > -1 AND ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make "conditional" `WHERE` clauses by pairing them with `OR` clauses.  Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE
    (@ProductID <= -1 OR ProductID = @ProductID)
    AND @ProductName = '' OR ProductName = @ProductName)
    -- etc.
```

That way if the "conditional check" is true than the second half of the `OR` clause isn't evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to be like below by making the conditions to be composite condition and you don't need a `CASE` expression. BTW, `IF .. ELSE` construct works only within a procedural body.

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE (@ProductID > -1 AND ProductID = @ProductID)
AND (@ProductName <> '' AND ProductName = @ProductName)
AND (@ProductManufacturerID > -1 AND ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the conditionals into requirements inside the WHERE clause.

```
IF(@ProductID > -1)
BEGIN
    ProductID = @ProductID
END
```

is equivalent to:

```
ProductID > -1 AND ProductID = @ProductID
```

,

```
IF(@ProductName <> '')
BEGIN
    ProductName = @ProductName 
END
```

is equivalent to:

```
ProductName <> '' AND ProductName = @ProductName
```

,

```
IF(@ProductManufacturerID > -1)
BEGIN
    ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID 
END
```

is equivalent to:

```
ProductManufacturerID > -1 AND ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID
```

So your final Query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE 
ProductID > -1 AND
ProductID = @ProductID AND
ProductName <> '' AND
ProductName = @ProductName AND
ProductManufacturerID > -1 AND
ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID
```

Comment: Your "equivalents" are not correct - e.g. if `@ProductID` is less than -1 then there would  be NO filter on `ProductID`.  Your equivalent would remove ALL records if `@ProductID` is less than -1.

Comment: I misunderstood what @user2112420 wanted to achieve.
To me, it looked like he wanted first to check if a product has ID > -1 and then check if it corresponds to the ID in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The when your parameter is intended to affect the select query the case will evaluate to 1 therefore making it part of the select statement, if not it will be 0 therefore it will not count because 0=1 will evaluate to false.

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE 
(CASE 
     WHEN @ProductId > -1 AND ProductId = @ProductId THEN 1 
     ELSE 0
 END) = 1
AND 
(CASE 
     WHEN @ProductName <> '' AND ProductName = @ProductName THEN 1 
     ELSE 0
END) = 1
AND 
(CASE
     WHEN @ProductManufacturerID > -1 AND ProductManufacturerID = @ProductManufacturerID THEN 1 
END);
```

Comment: You miss the part when comparing the @parameter with the row value

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Edited my answer, it should be fine now.