# How to do a single method for multipurpose results?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to make three type of queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table
SELECT * FROM table WHERE code IN (...)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE code IN (...) AND username = 'xxx'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'xxx'
```

I know I can build the query using 'if' sentences depending on the parameters, but I don't sure that it is well or not, for example I can use a preparedStatement like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE code IN(?) AND username = ?
```

But there's another problem, because, how to avoid (code IN(?)) or (AND username) depending on the parameters? The only way I know is using string concatenation like:

```
if (codes is not null) then
    query = query + " WHERE code IN( codes )"

if (username is not null) then
    query = query + " AND username = ? "
```

There is possible to build a unique query in a preparedStatement using mysql?

LIKE:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE if (codes is not null) code IN ( ? ) AND if (username is not null) username = 'xxx'
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? Can't you build the query dynamically in Java?

Comment: Yes, I want to make dinamically depending on the parameters, in order to no create a method per each

Comment: I don't think you have a problem here, you clearly demonstrate you know how to solve this by building your string in pieces using `if then` in your java code.  No, there is not SQL logic for adding/excluding WHERE statements based on existing parameters.  You can use IF or CASE logic to perform something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause but that's probably about as close as you'll get.

Comment: This is known as a "swiss army knife" method and is a programming anti-pattern. If you have three different queries then write three different methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the `where portion` is the 'non-common' factor here. You could pass a string for the Where clause and pass `null` if there was none. Something like this...

```
if you want `WHERE`...
    String WHERE = "code IN (...)"
    doWork(String WHERE);

else
    doWork(null);
```

And doWork would be something like...

```
private static void doWork(String WHERE) {
    String st = "SELECT * FROM table ";
    if(WHERE != null) {
        st += WHERE;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your query using java according to the conditions you need.

```
public String getQuery(String code, String username) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM `table`");

    boolean isCodeAdded = false;
    if (code != null) {
        sb.append(" WHERE `code` IN (?)");
        isCodeAdded = true;
    }

    if (username != null) {
        sb.append(isCodeAdded ? " AND" : " WHERE");
        sb.append(" `username` = ?");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```