# How to have conditional where clause based on parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following SQL,

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID Int

SELECT *
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
  WHERE OrderID = 10248
  AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

I want to make sure `IF @EmployeeID IS NULL` Then do not include `AND`

Something like,

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
  WHERE OrderID = 10248
  IF @EmployeeID IS NOT  NULL
  AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

I could think of creating a table variable and then filtering them based on parameter value , but is there a better way?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want:

```
WHERE OrderID = 10248 AND
      (@EmployeeId IS NULL OR EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID Int

SELECT *
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
  WHERE OrderID = 10248
  AND EmployeeID = ISNULL(@EmployeeID, EmployeeID )
```