# Change column being used in WHERE condition based on IF condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I apologize for the title - i was struggling coming up with something better.

Been doing some research on this and did find some [close examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause), however this is not quite what i need.

Basically i have a table with two columns that i want to evaluate under certain conditions. Column 1 is a identifier that can also be null. Column 2 is a SessionId that can change also.

Primarily i key off of column1, but when column1 is null i would like to key off of column2 instead. The example i linked above doesn't change the column being evaluated in the WHERE clause, only the value being used to evaluate the clause.

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate what i am trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE
IF Column1 NOT NULL
   Column1 = @myvariable1
ELSE
   Column2 LIKE '%' + @myvariable2 + '%'
```

Is something like this even possible? Can i switch the column to be evaluated in the WHERE clause based on the value of one of the columns?

I hope all that makes sense.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE (CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 = @myvariable1 THEN 1
            WHEN Column2 LIKE '%' + @myvariable2 + '%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
      END) = 1;
```

Comment: yup, this should work (if you add an `IS` to the `NOT NULL`)

Answer (score 1):

You should check for nullable on Column1 on both validation of the where clause in case you set @myvariable1 to null.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE (Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 = @myvariable1)
OR (Column1 IS NULL and Column2 LIKE '%' + @myvariable2 + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE  Column1 = @myvariable1
OR   ( Column1 IS NULL AND Column2 LIKE '%' + @myvariable2 + '%' )
```