# if else condition in where clause in ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

I'm trying to retrieve the records from the joined tables based on 2 condition like below:

```
Where if(b.enddate is null)
         a.starttime >= b.starttime
      else
         a.starttime >= b.starttime and a.endtime <= b.endtime
```

I have seen examples using case when but the result is not what I wanted. Please assist me to convert this condition into a proper sql format.

Comment: It's also possible to use boolean negated-parity conditions, like: `.. (b.enddate is null /* positive */ and (..)) or (b.enddate is not null /* negative */ and (..))`.

Comment: I suggest that you use the solution giveb by @Susang. But If you just have a XY-Problem and you just want  to know how to 'IF' in 'WHERE' then you should look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think** we can simply do this in short because in both the cases `a.starttime >= b.starttime` is applicable so we just need to handle `a.endtime <= b.endtime` condition in case of `b.enddate` is `NULL or NOT NULL` so I do as below:

```
WHERE a.starttime >= b.starttime and (b.enddate is null OR a.endtime <= b.endtime)
```

Comment: This is the solution to prefer, because it just uses boolean algebra to get rid of a double term and provides the most effective formular.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `case` expression, this can be done using `OR` in `WHERE` clause

```
... Where 
( b.enddate is null and a.starttime >= b.starttime)
or     
( b.enddate is not null and a.starttime >= b.starttime and a.endtime <= b.endtime)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
   WHERE (b.enddate is null AND a.starttime >= b.starttime) OR (b.enddate is not null AND a.starttime >= b.starttime and a.endtime <= b.endtime)
```

Answer (score 2):

for simplicity sake, you can try below sample conditional logic:

```
DECLARE @enddate datetime2(7);
SET @enddate = NULL;

SELECT @enddate;

IF @enddate IS NULL
    SELECT 1, 2 FROM dbo.table_a as a
    INNER JOIN dbo.table_b as b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.starttime >= b.starttime
ELSE
    SELECT 1, 2 FROM dbo.table_a as a
    INNER JOIN dbo.table_b as b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.starttime >= b.starttime and a.endtime <= b.endtime
```

this gives you the benefit of 2 separate execution plan. So if you decide to optimize your SQL statements, it would be much easier (like indexing, plan stability, move to sp, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try this sir,

```
   where (b.enddate is null and a.starttime >= b.starttime) OR (a.starttime >= b.starttime and a.endtime <= b.endtime)
```

Thanks :)