# how can put if condition in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please don't put duplicate with question [IF clause within WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause) ?
I think my question is difference, I have been tryed but I can't not run success with condition below.

How can put if condition between where in sql 
for example

```
        SELECT *
        FROM LocationOutsw W
        WHERE if(@p_type = 'ALL') then
            (W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%' OR W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%')
            if(@p_type == "NAME")
              W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%'
            if(@p_type == "DESCRIPTION ")
              W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%')
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? That query will run on max one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM LocationOutsw W
WHERE ( @p_type = 'ALL'
    AND ( W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%'
            OR W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%'
        )       
) 
OR (    @p_type = 'NAME'
    AND W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%'
)
OR ( @p_type = 'DESCRIPTION'
    AND W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%'
)
```

But I strongly recommend not to write your queries like so, because of wrong query plans you will get.

Answer (score 2):

I would use boolean expressions for this

```
    SELECT *
    FROM LocationOutsw W
    WHERE (@p_type = 'ALL' and W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%' OR W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%')
        or (@p_type = 'NAME' and W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%') 
        or (@p_type = 'DESCRIPTION' and W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%')
```

Be careful in syntax. Apostrophes have a different meaning than quotation mark.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommended this way.. It will do better..

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  LocationOutsw W
WHERE 
   (@p_type = 'ALL' AND
   (W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%'  OR  W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%'))
   OR
   (@p_type = 'NAME' AND W.NAME LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%')
   OR
   (@p_type = 'DESCRIPTION' AND W.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+ @p_search + '%')
```

And `'` Single quote for String not `"` Double Quote..