# SQL Where Clause with in IF Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

One variant of question asked [SQL: IF clause within WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause/87839)

Let's say `:DeptID` is a parameter passed to the SQL query and if `@DeptID` is null, then show all rows, else filter the result by `DeptID`.

Some pseudo code like

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
   IF :DeptID not = null 
     WHERE DeptID = :DeptID
   ELSE (no filter)
```

Looking for correct syntax suitable for PostgreSQL & MySQL

The expected result is: when the parameter `DeptID` passed in is `NULL`, then show all employees.

And when the parameter `DeptID` is passed as 10, show employees for the department with an ID of 10.

Comment: `where DeptID = :DeptID or :DeptID is null `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE :DeptID is null 
   OR :DeptID = DeptID
```

Comment: The Expected result is , when the parameter DeptID passed is Null then show all employees. And When the Parameter DeptID is passed as 10, show employees for that deptarment ID which is 10.

Comment: Yes, that is what the code does. Didn't you test it?