# How to use GROUP BY with MAX or SUM depending on conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL query with SQL Server (Microsoft SQL) that allows me to make different aggregations depending on a certain value. I want to do aggregations using MAX and SUM according to certain conditions (Moreover, I want to assume the maximum value but not exceeding a certain date (for example 2021/07/01)).

Let's take the following database:

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 2021-07-01 | 7 |
| name1 | 2021-02-02 | 10 |
| name1 | 2020-08-10 | 12 |
| name1 | 2020-03-07 | 5 |
| name2 | 2018-09-11 | 8 |
| name2 | 2019-04-04 | 2 |
| name2 | 2021-05-17 | 5 |
| name3 | 2020-03-03 | 0 |
| name3 | 2019-12-12 | 15 |
| name3 | 2018-10-12 | 11 |
| name4 | 2010-10-11 | 5 |
| name4 | 2012-02-26 | 7 |

I want to aggregate the values associated to the names `name1` and `name2` using MAX applied on their dates (i.e. I want to get their value associated to the oldest date) and I want to aggregate the values associated to the names `name3` and `name4` using the SUM function on their associated values.

The result would be :

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 12 |
| name2 | 5 |
| name3 | 26 |
| name4 | 12 |

I think using a CASE is a good idea but I haven't been able to implement it. I used the following post:

[SQL: IF clause within WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87821/sql-if-clause-within-where-clause)

I tried the following, but I'm not sure on how to use it and when:

```
SELET Name, Value FROM Table
WHERE Value LIKE
    CASE WHEN Name in (name1, name2) THEN
        MAX(Date)
    ELSE
        Date <= '2021-07-01'
GROUP BY Name
```

Concerning the MAX not exceeding a certain value, I have no idea how to do it since MAX takes a column as parameter...

I am sure that this problem is not so difficult to solve when you master SQL, but on my side it is quite new!

I thank you for reading me.

Comment: Please mention which database you are using.

Comment: @forpas just a mistake on my part, I edited the original post

Comment: @Jayadevan if you ask which database system I use, it's microsoft SQL, also I edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` and `SUM()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name,
       CASE 
         WHEN Name IN ('name1', 'name2') THEN
           MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= '2021-07-01' THEN Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)
         WHEN Name IN ('name3', 'name4') THEN
           SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)
       END Value    
FROM tablename
```

Or, conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name,
       CASE 
         WHEN Name IN ('name1', 'name2') THEN MAX(CASE WHEN Date <= '2021-07-01' THEN Value END)
         WHEN Name IN ('name3', 'name4') THEN SUM(Value)
       END Value    
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ebb620659bbd6f1f089fb4e3ceb2c731).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't have access to my database right now, I'll see what solution I adopt and if I have other questions before closing this topic

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation and some other conditional logic:

```
select name,
       coalesce(max(case when name in ('name1', 'name2') and max_date = date then value end),
                sum(value)
               )
from (select t.*,
             max(case when date <= '2021-07-01' then date end) over (partition by name) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't have access to my database right now, I'll see what solution I adopt and if I have other questions before closing this topic